# How do I unscrew these?

Tags: windows, screws, lock

[image: Holder on the window]
[image: End of the slider on the window]

I'm a college kid trying to sneak my boyfriend in my dorm window. The first section is the holder on the window, the second part is the end of the slider on the window. All I have to do is disconnect the slider. This looks definitely like a modification and is not integrated into the original piece.

Thank you :)

Comment: Not a home improvement question. Rather the reverse, actually.

Comment: Reduced to *what screws are these?*, would be a valid question (and most assuredly a dupe) but this version is much more fun.

Comment: Rose, while the brutal honesty of this question is hilarious, I would advise you to consider the very real possibility of property damage. What if you were to drop the window, worse what if you drop it *on something else like a car or a **person***? Legal repercussions are also an issue; I'm pretty sure this would at the very least count as vandalism, which while only a misdemeanor can seriously stymie up your life at the University. Might I suggest an SUV with fold down seats?

Comment: **Moderator note**: off-topic comments have been removed. Please see http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment for more information.

Answer (score 19):

We were all young once. You need a Torx screwdriver of the appropriate size https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torx

Actually due to the pin in the middle it is more technically security Torx. Harbour Freight will get you out of trouble cheaply.

Comment: Suggesting to, or helping someone, defeat a tamper-resistant screw is REALLY poor advice.

Comment: Why? Security through obscurity is no security at all

Comment: Or to phrase it another way, if all that was standing between her and unscrewing those screws was knowing which bit to use, I haven't done anything more than sped up the inevitable.

Comment: Torx are not tamper-resistant, they're just annoying. However, giving advice for how to climb through a window *is* questionable. But, if you didn't learn how to defeat every single TR fastener on the planet in college, you weren't paying enough attention.

Comment: Alternatively to using a security torx, just drill out the center pin and use a standard torx.

Comment: http://www.harborfreight.com/33-pc-security-bit-set-68459.html Only $5.99, look at the bits on the top right of the photo.

Comment: The right size flat head screwdriver will turn those when wedged in beside the little post.  Or the post will snap, allowing you to use a normal torx bit.